# Automatically logged out when searching using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

I am using selenium to automate search in a website.
Here is my code.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException


def init_driver():
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
    return driver


def lookup(driver, query):
    driver.get("www.example.com/search.php")
    try:
        button = driver.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
            (By.ID, "ad")))
        button.click()
        # query = "telugu"
        # box = driver.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
        #     (By.NAME, "keytext")))
        # box.send_keys(query)
        submit_text = "SEARCH"
        submit_button = driver.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
            (By.XPATH, "(//*[contains(text(), '" + submit_text + "')] | //*[@value='" + submit_text + "'])")))
        submit_button.click()
        print 'aaaa'
    except TimeoutException:
        print("Box or Button not found in google.com")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    driver = init_driver()
    lookup(driver, "Selenium")
    time.sleep(1000)
    driver.quit()
```

I log in to the site in firefox and then run this script.

Expected url opens up properly (This url open only when I am signed in),clicks the search button.

The results appear for a few seconds and then the Sign In screen is shown.

But I am not actually logged out because If I  open this site in a different tab,I am signed in.

I am not understanding this strange behaviour with selenium.Is the site somehow detecting that it is a bot which is trying to click?

Can anyone please tell me how to fix or bypass this?

Comment: Try the same steps manually.  This may be a product defect.

Comment: I tried it manually and it worked perfectly!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you are experiencing expected behavior with your product.  You mentioned that you manually open a browser and login, then run the script.  When your script runs, Selenium will open a new browser w/ a new profile, which means that it won't have any cookies that are probably being used for authentication on your site.

You will have to modify your script so that it logs in with valid credentials before it attempts to do the remaining steps.